# How to fix cordova.InAppBrowser.open and/or Intercom in iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser, html-framework-7, intercom

We have developed an app using Cordova and Framework 7. We have code that launches an external url:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system');
```

It works fine in a browser, it works fine on Android, but in iOS the app just sits there (still responsive), but it only launches the url in mobile safari if you double tap the home screen. This happens both in a simulator and on an actual iphone. What's strange is that the same exact behaviour and solution happens when using Intercom (a plugin for real time chatting).

```
intercom.displayMessenger();
```

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.